# Click listener not firing

Tags: c#

I'm not able to get a basic click listener to work.

I've created a base button with the (Name) of `button1`.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("button1 was clicked");
        }
```

When I run the application and click my button it doesn't fire.  I'm struggling to figure this out because I'm following the guide outlined here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfty2w4e.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're missing this line `button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);`, you should add this in the forms constructor.

If you go through the UI designer you can just drag the button onto the UI, then double click it and it will create the listener for you; everything you have there, plus the line above in the designer file, minus the `MessageBox.Show()`. This is the route I would recommend for creating all of your standard listeners.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the button on your form in the designer and view properties and select the events section, do you see a value next to the event "Click"? You should see the value "button1_click". If you don't see this, then that is your problem. You should be able to click the dropdown and select the button1_click event.